# IIS match query string and append NTLM to the URL

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, iis-10

I am trying to rewrite a URL once it matches the query string, unfortunately it doesn't rewrites to the desired URL. infact my rule does nothing. Can someone see what's wrong with the rule.

```
#First attempt:
<rule name="Rewrite to ntlm" enabled="true">
   <match url="\?workid=(.*)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="NTLM/{R:0}" />
</rule>

#Second attempt:
<rule name="Rewrite to ntlm" enabled="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="workid=(.*)" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="NTLM/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Actual URL:

```
https://example.com/site/?workid=5555
```

Desired URL:

```
https://example.com/site/NTLM/?workid=5555
```

Comment: Please enable FRT to learn what are the actual values of different request URL components, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then you know what are the patterns you need to write in `match` tags or in a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />         
        <action type="Redirect" url="/site/NTLM/?workid=5555" />
    </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If you have additional needs please let me know.